# Compare analytic model with numerical, mass spring system.

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, mathematical-physics

So I'm trying to solve a problem here and I have been working on it all day, clearly i'm in need of some guidance.

I have a rod of length $L$ and cross section area $A$, Young's modulus $E$ and constant density $\rho$. Now I want to study longitudinal waves in this rod when its end is attached to a wall. So first i derive the wave equation as it is done in my book and I arrive with this

$$
u_{tt}-c^2u_{xx}=0\\
u(0,t)=u(L,t)=0
$$

where u(x,t) is the displacement in point $x$ at time $t$ and $c=\sqrt{\frac{E}{\rho}}$.

I'm pretty sure that this is correct since I have a few examples in my book that are stated like this. Now I want to detect the eigenfrequency so I separate the variables and go through all that (not so important for this problem) and arrive with

$$
\omega_n = \frac{\pi}{L}\sqrt{\frac{E}{\rho}}\,n \,\,, \, n=1,2,3,..
$$

and this again seems right, dimensions checks out and the book have some similar examples.

Ok so now the first part seems okay and I move on to the next problem, a numerical approximation of this. The idea is to use $N+1$ number of strings along with $N$ masses with mass $M$, and then put these together in a long chain. So this model will end up looking like a system

$$
X'' =\frac{k}{m}AX = \frac{k}{m} \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-2 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -2 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & -2 \end{array} \right) X
$$

where m is the mass of these little masses and k is the constant for the springs. Now A can get how big as we want (size depends on N), just expand with $-2$ and $1$ along the diagonals and zeros on the upper and lower triangle, like a band matrix. Now I'm given the mass $ m = \frac{\rho A L}{N+1}$ and I'm asked again to find the eigenfrequencies for this numerical problem in the case for $N= 25$ and compare it with my first model, then chose the constant $k$ so the frequencies for these two models agree. I'm bit lost here but I ran $E = eig(A)$ in MATLAB and took

$$
\omega_n = \sqrt{\frac{k}{m}E(n)} = \sqrt{\frac{k(N+1)}{\rho A L}E(n)}
$$
and then I tried to compare this with my first model but nothing agrees, the eigenfrequencies for my first model clearly grows as $n$ gets bigger and all the values of $E(n)$ are negative. I changes the sign in my matrix and that fixes the problem for this but the numbers aren't even correct here. I have worked on this for 10 hours now, It would mean a lot if someone could take the time to give me some advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why this expression for $c$? If I recall correctly then
$$
c=\sqrt{\frac{E}{\rho}}\,.
$$

Second, the eigenvalues you found are the eigenvalues of the operator
$$
-\frac{d^2}{dx^2},
$$
and the eigenvalues are $\omega_n^2$, it is easier to deal with squares, hence to relate everything you need to find the eigenvalues of $-A$ (you use $A$ in two different contexts).

Your expression for $m$ is correct.

Now try to figure out your $k$. And compare with the spoiler:

> $$\displaystyle k=\frac{EA}{h}\,,\quad h=\frac{L}{N+1}\,.$$

Comment: But isn't the eigenfrequency just the root of the eigenvalues in these problems? Also I need compare these frequencies with the ones I found at the beginning but I don't even know what I should compare. I understand what you are saying but I can't apply it to this problem, I think i'm just too confused about what to do.

Comment: And I think your expression for $c$ is the one for one dimensional density? I will double check these details, but the big problem is at the end, I need to find those frequencies and understand the whole solution.

Comment: @Danny yes, eigenfrequencies are the roots of eigenvalues. But it saves some time not to calculate roots. All the pieces to solve your problem are in your question and my comments.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to scribble a bit more and if I don't have it tomorrow or something I might comment something new haha! Thank you very much!

Comment: I got one more question before I go, which of the eigenvalues from $-A$ should I compare what which of the first ones? The 6th eigenvalue from this $-A$ doesn't not relate to $n=6$ in the first formula, because that will change if we pick a larger N? This is so frustrating...

Comment: Here is one more hint: Compare the eigenvalues of $-A$ and $\pi^2n^2/(N+1)^2,\,n=1,2,\ldots$

Comment: yeah, they do not agree :S The highest eigenvalue from -A is roughly 4 and if i plug in $n=25$, $N=25$ in you formula above i get roughly 9.

Comment: Compare from the other end, for n=1,2,3

Comment: Yes for $n=1$ they agree. But I can't see where you formula from this is coming from. Now i'm only confirming number without even knowing the connection it seems :S

Comment: @Danny, then I would advise you to have some rest and rethink this problem afterwards taking into account all the points I made. Good luck.

Comment: Ok man, I'm not going to make this since i've been trying for the past 6 hours. I have the feeling that I will understand everything if someone just explain it but I will have to wait for tomorrow then and ask my professor. Thanks for taking your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35515/discussion-between-danny-and-artem).

Comment: @Danny, I still can answer your questions here if you any.